# How to fix Incorrect filesystem property information?

Tags: nautilus, mount, filesystem, partitioning

My hard drive has four partitions.

- Windows 80gb
- Ubuntu Linux 70gb
- Storage 530gb
- Recovery 14gb

I used Gparted (booted Linux from pen drive) to remove 30 GB from storage and subsequently re-allot it to Ubuntu Linux (Yes that's 100 for Linux, a lot, I know. Just don't worry about it lol. I'm new.)
That finally finished and my partitions show up as their respective new sizes, however, the properties of my "storage" partition still show it holding the extra 30gb.

The partition is 500gb but the filesystem properties still says 530gb like before, how do I fix this?

Comment: @Alaa not quite, this problem is about the "storage" file system being to big for the partition.

Comment: What file system do you have on "Storage"?

Comment: Could you add the output of `df -h` and `fdisk -l`?